# Java static and non-static variables in the same class

Tags: java, variables, static, non-static

I need some help clarifying static and non-static variables. It is my understanding that static variables have the same value across all instances of a class. However, suppose I have a mix of static and non-static variables in the same class. When I reference a static variable, regardless of which instance is used, I will get the same value? Yet when I reference a non-static variable I will get the value associated with that particular class? That seems like a memory management nightmare. Is this really how it works and how is static memory handled? Are multiple copies of the variable created in each instance and then somehow sync'ed or is a reference by address created in each instance? Are there any pitfalls using a mix of static and non-static variables in the same class? TIA.

Comment: `When I reference a static variable, regardless of which instance is used` -> you do not need (and shall not) use an instance to get the value of the static variable. You should rather get its value with this syntax : `YourClass.YOUR_STATIC_FINAL_VARIABLE` for example. As you can see, there is no need for `new YourClass().something`.

Comment: Thanks but that reply is not what I am doing. I use 'myclass1=new MyClass(); myclass2=new MyClass();'. Then I reference the static variable as 'myclass1.something' or 'myclass2.something' and expect them to have the same value. Meanwhile, 'myclass1.somethingelse' and 'myclass2.somethingelse' would have different values. That is what I am trying to verify and to know if there are any pitfalls doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct in your assertion ... sort-of.  Statics aren't really shared between instances of the class because you don't *need* a class instance to reference one.

```
public class Foo {
   public static String MYSTRING = "test";
}
```

can be accessed without an instance of Foo

```
String localString = Foo.MYSTRING;
```

I wouldn't really worry much about how the JVM chooses to store the memory references for the static variables, that is an implementation detail that is delegated to the JVM designer.

There aren't any pitfalls to having a class that defines both static and non-static (instance) variables, it happens all the time and is perfectly natural ... as long as you understand how statics work, which it seems that you do.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that was the case but just needed the warm and fuzzies.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from [OCA Java SE 7 Programmer I Certification Guide: Prepare for the 1ZO-803 exam](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617291048):

> **STATIC VARIABLES**
>
> static variables belong to a class. They are common to all instances of a class and aren’t unique to any instance of a class. static attributes exist independently of any instances of a class and may be accessed even when no instances of the class have been created. You can compare a static variable with a shared variable. A static variable is shared by all of the objects of a class.
>
> **STATIC METHODS**
>
> Static methods aren’t associated with objects and can’t use any of the instance variables of a class. You can define static methods to access or manipulate static variables
>
> You can also use static methods to define utility methods, which are methods that usually manipulate the method parameters to compute and return an appropriate value
>
> The non-private static variables and methods are inherited by derived classes. The static members aren’t involved in runtime polymorphism. You can’t override the static members in a derived class, but you can redefine them. Any discussion of static methods and their behavior can be quite confusing if you aren’t aware of inheritance and derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

`Static` variables are the same throughout the program, since they are not instantiated. This is indeed the whole point of having static variables. They are not "somehow the same value", they are the same value because they are never instantiated and there's only ever one static variable of the same name from the same class during run time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the 'memory logic' behind, but I've created an example

```
public class TestClass {

private static int a = 1;
private int b = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestClass firstInstance = new TestClass();
    TestClass secondInstance = new TestClass();

    // 'a' shouldn't be accessed like firstInstance.a, use TestClass.a instead(!)
    System.out.println("firstInstance  a: "+firstInstance.a+" b: "+firstInstance.b);  // firstInstance  a: 1 b: 1
    System.out.println("secondInstance a: "+secondInstance.a+" b: "+secondInstance.b);// secondInstance a: 1 b: 1

    firstInstance.a = 2; 
    firstInstance.b = 2;

    System.out.println("firstInstance  a: "+firstInstance.a+" b: "+firstInstance.b);  //firstInstance  a: 2 b: 2
    System.out.println("secondInstance a: "+secondInstance.a+" b: "+secondInstance.b);//secondInstance a: 2 b: 1 
    //a is now 2 also for 'secondInstance' because it's static, secondInstance.b didn't change because b exists specifically for each instance 

    /*
     * You can access 'a' even when no instance of TestClass exists
     * think about a simple Dog class where the amount of legs is 4 for every dog, so you can make it static, 
     * but not every Dog has the same name, so it wouldn't be clever to make the name static
     */
}
}
```